# Xcode 5 not showing project configuration options

Tags: xcode5

While creating the new project Xcode doesn't show options like

1. Automatic Reference Counting
2. Use Story Boards.
3. and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 5 without Storyboard and ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234172/xcode-5-without-storyboard-and-arc)

Comment: It knows what's best for you.  Do not resist.

Comment: @Hot Licks But, I don't know what exactly it is choosing. And i am a beginner in this field. So, I wish to use things like .xib files instead of storyboards for learning purposes

Comment: I usually just start with an empty project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 5 and higher doesn't show these options because they now represent default behavior. Storyboards are included by default as is ARC. There is nothing needed to enable these options.