# xcode 5 - open a project without story board

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xcode5

I've recently downloaded the new xCode from the developers' site, and everywhere I look, I can't find a solution as to how to open a project *without* storyboard.

It's important to me because I want to keep my apps working on iOS 4.3.

The way I do it, is by opening the project in the old version and then opening it in the new one. But there must be another way.

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you to start - i do hope there is a more elegant solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17922253/653513

Comment: @rokjarc No there isn't and honestly I don't see why there should be. There soooo few people out there running iOS 4.3 (even iOS 5 is rare!) so it's really understandable that apple doesn't support it any more for new software.

Comment: @Idan Why do you want to support iOS 4.3?

Comment: @HAS: well there are few of us who really don't like to use storyboards at all :)

Comment: While I can understand that you need to accept that Apple decided that storyboards are the future and we have to adjust to that.

Comment: @HAS I need to support it beacuse the company that i work for wants 
and i just - dont like it :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

STEPS FOR REMOVE STORY BOARD

1) Remove Main.storyboard file from your project.

2) Add new files with xib for your controller , if it is not added in compiled sources in build phases then add there manually.

3) Remove Main storyboard file base name from plist.

4) Change appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions file and add :

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

just like :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

     // Override point for customization after application launch.

     TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
     UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:test];
     self.window.rootViewController = nav;

     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

     return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just pick the Empty Application template, my friend

[image]

Comment: but the problem is when i need a "master detail template"

Comment: the "master detail template" is nothing but 2 view controllers: a tableview controller, and a detail view controller. you can construct the similar thing all from scratch, I suggest you should learn to build this sample from scratch just to understand the basics.

Comment: yes, that's what i think ill going to do.

thanks.