# How do I create a new project in Xcode5 without using storyboard?

Tags: storyboard, xcode5

Is there any option available in Xcode5 to create a new project without storyboard enabled?

Comment: You need to create Empty Application

Answer (score 2):

From here you can get whole idea, its good solution :

[xcode 5 - open a project without story board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932473/xcode-5-open-a-project-without-story-board)

STEPS FOR REMOVE STORY BOARD

1) Remove Main.storyboard file from your project.

2) Add new files with xib for your controller , if it is not added in compiled sources in build phases then add there manually.

3) Remove Main storyboard file base name from plist.

4) Change appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions file and add :

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

just like :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

     // Override point for customization after application launch.

     TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
     UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:test];
     self.window.rootViewController = nav;

     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

     return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool that converts Xcode 4's project templates to Xcode 5, so you can once again create projects with or without storyboards. You can find it here on GitHub: https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/Xcode4templates

More information is available in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19777356/171933

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

- Create an empty project.

Option 2:

- Delete the storyboard file
- Erase "Main interface" (defaults to "Main") in target settings
- In app's info.plist remove the 'Main storyboard file name' entry
- Remove all Storyboard-related stuff from the auto generated app code
- Instantiate a UIWindow, instantiate and set its rootViewController, etc.
- Enjoy