# Xcode 5.0 missing "Use XXX" checkboxes in project templates

Tags: xcode5

When I was using Xcode 4.6, there were checkbox options like:

- Use Storyboards
- Use Automatic Reference Counting
- Include Unit Tests

But in Xcode 5.0, I can no longer see them in all of the templates, except "Use Core Data" option remains in certain templates:
[image: Empty Application template]

Am I having corrupted templates or it is just normal in the new Xcode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 5 without Storyboard and ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234172/xcode-5-without-storyboard-and-arc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal with XCode 5.

You are mandatory to create a project using storyboard and remove it if you want to use XIB...

But, with [this link](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/xcode4-template-documentation/) you can download a good document to explain how create custom template with XCode.

To add your own template you need to go :

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/

and create the folder Templates if doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

To get a basic Single View project without a Storyboard, like the old template behaviour:

- File > New Project > Empty Project
- Click on Project in navigator and delete the Unit Test target
- Right-click on unit tests in navigator

  - Click Delete
  - Click Move to Trash
- Click on Project "New File..." > iOS > CocoaTouch > Objective-C Class
- Sub-class of UIViewController

  - check the "With XIB for user interface" box
  - enter class name, eg MyViewController

Add at the top of AppDelegate.m

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
```

Then in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, insert three lines of code:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.window setRootViewController:vc];

// insert just above this line, which was already created by the template
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

(Pitching this at the level of someone who might for example be following a tutorial and thus struggling to match it to what is going on with XCode 5)