# Get an XIB in iOS 7 S.D.K

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, ios7, xib

I have been using iOS for the past couple of months and what i have been doing is when i Click Single View Application, a default View Controller would appear with an XIB.
But with iOS 7, the XIB don't seem to appear, rather the storyboard appears.
I have no idea how to work with Storyboard's. I have neither used them in the past nor do i want to use them in the near Future. Do i always need to go ahead with an empty view and then add the relevant ViewController's

Please let me know if i am doing something silly or is it the new iOS 7 default behavior.

I did try to get into more detail's but could not get relevant answers on Google as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234172/xcode-5-without-storyboard-and-arc

Comment: You should use storybord..and its not a big deal.. its petty much easy stuff ... main advantage is you could able to see all of your uiviewcontroller at one place ..

Comment: @amitabha : Probably you are right.Would definitely look into it.

Comment: have a look at this http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: @amitabha :  Thank You ... i have seen your Stack's account and very impressed by the knowledge you possess. Is there any other way i can connect to you apart from stack ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Step 1` Create New Project

`Step 2` Select "Single View Application" -> Next

`Step 3` Set ProjectName and other settings -> Next

`Step 4` Save Project at location -> create

`Step 5` Select Project in Navigator Panel in Left

`Step 6` "Remove Main.storyboard" file from project

`Step 7` "Add New .xib file in Project"

`Step 8` Set Main Interface to your .xib file in "General Tab" on right panel. [image: refer screenshot attached]

`Step 9` Paste following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7 compliance the correct XIB you need to use is the interface builder document named: **Application**, as your primary nib.