# Receiving a "Check dependencies warning: skipping file" error in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcode5, google-maps-sdk-ios

I've been carefully following the directions for '[Adding the Google Maps SDK for iOS to your project](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project)' with the Google Maps iOS 1.5.0 SDK and Xcode 5.0, while building to an iPhone 4S.
When building the project, I get the following warning:

```
Check dependencies

warning: skipping file '/Users/Michael/iOS Development/C&G rough draft/ComingAndGoingRoughDraft/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GoogleMaps.bundle' (unexpected file type 'wrapper.plug-in' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)
```

Due to this warning, its skipping GoogleMaps.bundle and my app
fails to have an embedded Google Map. What am I overlooking with this problem?

Additionally, since the [Google Map instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project) don't appear to be updated for Xcode 5, I am manually following these [instruction to remove Storyboards from my Single-View Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17922253/914778).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The way to get rid of this error is to be sure to add the GoogleMaps.bundle only to the Frameworks folder in the Project Navigator to the left (do this by dragging and dropping the bundle onto the Frameworks folder).

Do **not** add the GoogleMaps.bundle to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" under General, **nor** to the "Link Binaries with Libraries" under Build Phases.

Unfortunately, this is only a half-answer. It solves the warning, but Google Maps still does not appear in my app, leaving only a black void where a map should be.

[image: Add the bundle file to the Frameworks file on the left, not the Linked Libraries window on the right]

---

More specifically, first go to **Build Phases**
 section of the project. Check underneath the 'Link Binary with Libararies' section, and make sure the bundle file is NOT there (if it is, select it, and click the minus to remove it).
Go to **General** section and look under Linked Frameworks and Libraries to make sure the bundle file is not there either.

[image: Go to Project Navigator, then drag bundle file onto Frameworks folder]

Now, click on Project Navigator (the small folder icon), then drag and drop the bundle file onto the Frameworks folder. It will ask if you want to 'copy files into the destination group's folder'. We'll assume that you've already copied the Google Maps Framework itself earlier, so in this case, leave the Copy Items unchecked (otherwise we'd have redundant files). Now the warning should be resolved.

Comment: Can you document what you are doing step by step so I can replicate it?

Comment: Brett, let me know if the changes are detailed enough.