# MRC in iOS7 and Xcode5

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5

Cant we run ios project developed using MRC(Manual Reference Counting) which is for iOS6? Does not Xcode 5 allow to code using MRC as it supports ARC?  Can we use only ARC in Xcode 5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 5 without Storyboard and ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234172/xcode-5-without-storyboard-and-arc)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. 
Simply set build setting  `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting` to `No`

(Click Project->Build Settings)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Targets --> BuildPhases-->Compile Source here you can see list of .m files double click on any  .m file and write -fno-objc-arc  . Now you can Use MRC in your code , make sure you write code for all .m (-fno-objc-arc)